# How to pass an object as props in a map function in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm trying to pass props to a child component. The problem I am getting is that one of the properties i'm to pass is an array. The registrants array looks like this:

```json
{
  name: "Rowan Powell",
  _id: "58658484d139c337601cfb6d",
  updatedOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:48.185Z",
  createdOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:48.185Z"
},
{
  name: "Savannah Powell",
  _id: "58658488d139c337601cfb6e",
  updatedOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:52.145Z",
  createdOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:52.145Z"
}
```

If I try to pass the registered prop like below I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {name, _id, updatedOn, createdOn}). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap
>   the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

```js
 return (
        <div>
            {this.state.events.map((event, key) => {
             return (
                    <div key={key}>
                        <Event 
                            title={event.title}
                            date={event.date}
                            time={event.time}
                            description={event.description}
                            presentor={event.presentor}
                            location={event.location}
                            registered={event.registrants}
                            max_reg={event.max_reg}
                            id={event._id} />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Seems as if the error is thrown inside the render of the `Event` component. Could you show the code?

Comment: Perfect that actually helped. I found the error in the child component. Thank you!

Comment: this.state.events should be array.  and array can contain any object. then you can  use map on it.

Answer (score 1):

To be a little more organized your component should look something like the code below. In your parent component, you can run a function that returns an array of your `Event` child components. The `map` function in `renderChildren` will return an array. Therefore, you can just return the result of that function. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
import React from 'react'

// This is your child component:
import Event from './Event'


export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {events: []}
  }
  renderChildren(events) {
    return events.maps((event, key) => {
      return (
        <div key={key}>
          <Event
            title={event.title}
            date={event.date}
            time={event.time}
            description={event.description}
            presentor={event.presentor}
            location={event.location}
            registered={event.registrants}
            max_reg={event.max_reg}
            id={event._id}
          />
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='ParentComponent'>
        {this.renderChildren(this.state.events)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
this.state= {events: [{
      name: "Rowan Powell",
      _id: "58658484d139c337601cfb6d",
      updatedOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:48.185Z",
      createdOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:48.185Z"
    },
    {
      name: "Savannah Powell",
      _id: "58658488d139c337601cfb6e",
      updatedOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:52.145Z",
      createdOn: "2016-12-29T21:47:52.145Z"
    }]};
    // change key to index
     return (
            <div>
                {this.state.events.map((event, index) => {
                 return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <Event 
                                title={event.title}
                                date={event.date}
                                time={event.time}
                                description={event.description}
                                presentor={event.presentor}
                                location={event.location}
                                registered={event.registrants}
                                max_reg={event.max_reg}
                                id={event._id} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
```